# Page scrolls on mobile devices due to hidden menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, hamburger-menu

*****UPDATE AT BOTTOM: I discovered a partial solution, but still not a total solution. So, I will leave my question up.*****

I have made a new webpage, and placed the hamburger menu on the top right of the screen, and hidden it off screen when not selected. The code is too lengthy to copy/paste here, but you can view source of my new page at this URL: https://ContractWithAmerica2.com

My problem is this: When I scroll up and down on my mobile device, and don't scroll "exactly" up/down, the screen slides to the left or right due to the extra content, (content is this: my hamburger menu which I hid to the right of the visible viewport).

Now, my desktop behaves: I was able to insert HTML CSS code that removes the scrollbar; however, on my smartphone, the scroll is not disabled-- and it is annoying to me (and to others).

Now, I found another webpage with HTML and CSS that, like my page, has a hamburger menu on top-right, so I thought I'd be "smart" and copy it. That page is at this URL:

https://www.WesternJournal.com

However, it uses a form of CSS that draws from a stylesheet, and yet even when I tried copying their stylesheet method, I was unable.

My request is for assistance in writing CSS directly into my page's HTML code (which makes my page more stable, as it will not need to send a "call" for a stylesheet), that will do this.

My HTML and CSS are, so far, good in making my page work-- except for this one flaw. Does anyone know the proper code to make my page "lock" and stop the left-right scrolling when my menu is hidden? Like the Western Journal website does? When scrolling on that page, it scrolls up/down ONLY-- and does not allow me to scroll to the left-right, exposing the hidden menu-- as does my page.

P.S.: I looked all over StackOverflow, but no answers prior given have fixed this problem for me, so I must ask de novo.

Thanks!

Gordon, new StackOverflow member!

UPDATE: Remember, when I said I discovered a partial solution at top? Here is my update:

Initially, I had this code:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">`

But just earlier today saw some post some place with newer info, and I updated that section to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

In other words, the newer code I found online had the "user-scalable=no" attribute, plus some code specific to Apple devices.

Plus, prior versions had this code:

```
<style>body{overflow-x: hidden;}</style>
```

But my newer version added a few more bells and whistles:

```
<style>body{overflow-x: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%;}</style>
```

When I ran the tests, however, it worked ok only on CHROME (both desktop and mobile device), where both the scrollbar disappeared, and the touch screen attempts to scroll "left-to-right" were finally stopped. (I.e., my menu, hidden off-screen, stayed hidden until clicked.)

My "desktop" OPERA browser worked ok, but, while my desktop MOZILLA FIREFOX hid the scroll bar (good), it still let me manually scroll (with the arrow keys). My mobile experience was even worse:

Both the SAMSUNG INTERNET BROWSER and my OPERA BROWSER on my smartphone (mobile device) allowed the page to scroll left-to-right, meaning users who scrolled "down," when reading would scroll to the left, exposing the hidden menu if they didn't scroll "exactly" top-to-bottom.

In other words, only GOOGLE'S CHROME worked ok on my mobile device.

Can anyone else weigh in?

URL: https://ContractWithAmerica2.com And:  Mirror pages are https://GordonWatts.com/m.index.html and https://GordonWayneWatts.com/m.index.html

Call me old fashioned, but I like a "spare tire" (redundancy) on the Internet Highway, and so I cross-post to several mirrors.

Thank you if anyone can help me get it to work in ALL browsers!

Gordon Wayne Watts, FLORIDA

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgFTW.png)